# dict to xlsx conversion prints incorrectly

Tags: python, dictionary, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to print data from a dictionary, i.e.:

```
fieldsDict = {'1': 'abc', '2': 'def', '3': 'ghi'}
```

Using xlsxwriter and the below snippet of code:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('stuff')

colNum = 0
for key, value in fieldsDict.items():
    worksheet.write(0, colNum, key)
    worksheet.write_column(1, colNum, value)
    colNum += 1

workbook.close()
```

However, when I execute this, I get the an excel document that looks like:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | d | g |
| b | e | h |
| c | f | i |

Instead of my goal, which would make the sheet look like:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | ghi |

It looks like my values are being split into each individual character. However, when I attempt to use a `.join('')` to bring them back together, my rows disappear completely.

Comment: why did you use `write_column()` ?

Comment: To amplify, @AcaNg, you probably just want `write_string()`. `write_column` will use the input to iterate over the data (strings are iterable as a series of letters) and make an entry for each value.

Comment: That worked! Thank you both! To answer the initial question, this is my first time writing data using xlsxwriter and I used the example code from [link](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data.html).

Comment: from [the doc](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_column): "The `write()` method is called for each element of the data", in this case I think both `write()` and `write_string()` will work fine